# How do I indent without hiding parts of shadows?

Tags: css, shadow, shadowbox

I have content that I'd like to align vertically, so I'm using this simple class to indent:

```
.indent-1 {
    margin-left: 144px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works fine in most cases, but if I have a box with a **drop shadow** within the indented content, the `overlfow: hidden` hides part of the shadow.

Is there a way to accomplish this indentation without sacrificing shadows?

**ANSWERED**

Here is the complete style to get the desired effect, shadows intact:

```
.indent-1 {
    margin-left: 120px;
    padding-left: 24px; 
    /* margin + padding = 144 */

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily; I'm using a margin now and it "overwrites" the left part of the shadow (the overflow) of my indented box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding to indent-1.